# No module named py-swagger-generator

Tags: python, pip, path

I want to use py-swagger-generator, but it doesnt work after pip installing...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjVcs.png)
result of "py-swagger-generator --build":
py-swagger-generator : The name "py-swagger-generator" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, and then
try again.

I tried to add python path to PATH, sys.path, and run py-swagger-generator with python -m.
enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwiFW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1eEe.png)

Answer (score 1):

there is success when I tried to `pip3 install py-swagger-generator`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQTG.png)

I saw your first picture, I think the problem is about User Permission

you can check the permission of the site-package directory or your account

Comment: the module has already been downloaded using the usual pip install, but  "py-swagger-generator --build" does not work :(